# How to find out data transfer latency with QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

I am using QNetworkAccessManager to `GET` certain data. Is it possible to know what time was spent in the actual transfer vs initial connection latency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signal "downloadProgress" on QNetworkReply gives an indication of the "Start" & "End" time of the actual download process when that signal is emitted for the first and last time. So defining a slot for the signal and doing the calculations right, should handle the latency part.